# Appending data to dataframe inside loop

Tags: r

Hell there

I am trying to use R to go through a set of PDF files to count characters on specific pages inside. My goal is to calculate a mean page length

I have used the following code

```
numberOfChars <- data.frame(case = character(), Ints=integer(),Ints2=integer())


files <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = "*.pdf",
                    full.names = TRUE)
for (file in files) {
    firstPage <- heading_search(file, headings = "1. B10: Project description", path = TRUE)[2] + 1
    lastPage <- firstPage + 1
    df <- nchar(pdf_text(file)[firstPage[1, 1]:lastPage[1, 1]])
    add_row(numberOfChars, case = file, Ints = as.data.frame(df))
}
```

While the code runs, the resulting dataframe does not contain anything.

As this point I am stumped. What do you suggest doing?

Comment: Adding rows aka "growing objects" is chapter 2 from the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). It's a bad thing to do, and while it functionally works, it scales horribly. It is best to come up with the data and add rows only once at the end.

Comment: You never assign the last line of loop to anything. So the empty `numberOfChars` never changes!

Comment: `add_row` (and most R functions) works in a *functional* method, which means they don't change the variable itself, they return the new object. You need to capture it into a variable (whether the same or a new variable, your choice).